# Adding Restricted Sites To Windows Internet Options

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I want to add a restricted site in the Internet options under the security tab on Windows.

[image]

Is there any batch script for this? Alternatively, does [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) have this functionality? I want to include this feature in my Java application.

One last resort would probably be to edit the registry. Restricted domains are stored here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains
```

Comment: IE settings are stored here : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer  , but I'm not sure about the restricted sites.You can change this option to see what will happen in the registry.OR you can change your hosts gile

Comment: +npocmaka:
I figured out where the restricted sites are stored in the registry, see my edited original post.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [`Regshot`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/) to find out changes in the registry before and after adding a restricted site. Then I exported the entry as `.reg` file which then can be executed to add the domain(s) back to the registry.

Adding the site https://example.com results in the following .reg file when the entry is exported:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\example.com]
"https"=dword:00000004
```

Comment: which reg entries has been changed?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this through the registry is the only way - as I see you've worked out. Just a few hints to help you out.

You can set registry entries via the command prompt or as a single line within a batch file. e.g. `reg add "hkcu\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\example.com" /v * /t REG_DWORD /d 2`

The Dword value determines which internet zone the *.example.com entry goes to. 0 = my computer, 1 = local intranet, 2 = trusted sites, 3 = internet, 4 = restricted sites